# Flutter app crash on release mode reading PDF

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a pdf reader in my app, with this function I get de pdf from URL and save the file in local path

```
  Future<File> getFileFromUrl(String url) async {
    try {
      var data = await http.get(url);
      var bytes = data.bodyBytes;
      var dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
      File file = File("${dir.path}/some.pdf");

      File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      return urlFile;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Error opening url file");
    }
  }
```

After this process, I call a class to show this PDF in a new route

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';

class CustomPdfView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String urlPdf;

  CustomPdfView(
    this.title,
    this.urlPdf
  );

  @override
  _CustomPdfViewState createState() => _CustomPdfViewState();
}

class _CustomPdfViewState extends State<CustomPdfView> {
  //int _totalPages = 0;
  //int _currentPage = 0;
  bool pdfReady = false;
  //PDFViewController _pdfViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Aqui entra antes: ${widget.urlPdf}');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          PDFView(
            filePath: widget.urlPdf,
            autoSpacing: true,
            enableSwipe: true,
            pageSnap: true,
            swipeHorizontal: true,
            nightMode: false,
            onError: (e) {
              print("error $e");
            },
            onRender: (_pages) {
              setState(() {
                //_totalPages = _pages;
                pdfReady = true;
              });
            },
            onViewCreated: (PDFViewController vc) {
              //_pdfViewController = vc;
            },
            onPageChanged: (int page, int total) {
              setState(() {});
            },
            onPageError: (page, e) {},
          ),
          !pdfReady
              ? Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Offstage()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

All works fine in debug mode, but when I run my app on release, the app crashes in CustomPdfView.

I don't know what is the error, I already added, STORAGE permissions in my /app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I don't know how can I get error line in the console, because the app is running on release.

Comment: Which version of  flutter_pdfview you are using?

Comment: If you use proguard, you should include this line.

-keep class com.shockwave.**

Comment: I'm using Flutter 1.15.3

Comment: And I'm not using proguard.

Comment: @GarnachaSoft How can you use version 1.15.3. There is no version available like this. The latest version of till today flutter_pdfview 1.0.2+4 that is published on Jun 15, 2020. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

However, it still crashes on load pdf in android in release mode.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar 1.15.3 is my flutter version, not plugin version.

Comment: @GarnachaSoft Hey it's okay but Dev asked for flutter_pdfview version. By the way, did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

same issue.....
i fixed that one

1. clean your project after build your apk

if still problem persist
than try these commands

flutter build apk --no-shrink

flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi --no-shrink

Answer (score 0):

your way of reading pdf is very nice, here you try to launch pdf in your app,

i almost did the same way.

where i was getting Uint8List from url of pdf, and reading it in my app using [printing 5.9.3](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

but when size of pdf or number of pages more then my app keep getting crash, and also before launching pdf in my app i need to save it locally as you did.

so, to solve this i just need to use [flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.4.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview)

using this flutter_cached_pdfview i don't need to save pdf locally, just pass the url of pdf and you can launch it in your app without worrying about size of pdf or number of pages in pdf.

i just launch using a button and i pass url of pdf

```
  // navigate in another screen
   onPressed: () => nextScreen(
                          PDFViewerPage(
                            url: widget.magazineModel.fileUrl,
                            title: widget.magazineModel.name,
                          ),
                        ),
```

and MyPdfViewerPage is below

```
class PDFViewerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final String title;
  const PDFViewerPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('url : $url');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const LeadingIconComponent(), // for popScreen()
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: const PDF().cachedFromUrl(
        Uri.parse(url).toString(),
        placeholder: (progress) => const LoadingComponent(),
        errorWidget: (error) {
          debugPrint('errorInOprnPDF : $error');
          return const ErrorPageComponent(
            title: 'File Not Exist',
            content: "This file is either removed or not valid",
            image: "assets/images/empty_data_component/new data not found.svg",
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an error for ParentData Widget. Mine shown this error:

```
 type 'ParentData' is not a subtype of type 'FlexParentData' in type cast
```

The app works fine with this error showing in debug mode but not in release mode. [This](https://www.dhiwise.com/post/incorrect-use-of-parentdatawidget-in-flutter-a-guide) website helped me fix that error. Basically, I was using Expanded under Container. So I used it the other way- Container under Expanded. That led to another error. Something about unconstrained height restraints. I followed the instructions for the log for that error.

```
Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
constraints provided by the parent.
```

I used Flexible instead of Expanded and set the mainAxixSize to MainAxisSize.min. Hope this helps.