# How to load and present a PDF file from the web in Flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to fetch a PDF file from a URL, and to present it in my Flutter app (for both Android and iOS).

I've searched the web and SO for answers on how to present a fetched PDF file in Flutter, but all I could find was how to present a locally pre-added PDF file.

I've also searched for packages doing the same, but I couldn't find one that worked.

**Example**:

I'm trying to fetch [this](http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf) PDF file for example, and to present it inside a Flutter widget screen in my app.

Does anyone know how can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use flutter_pdfview package.

1. Add Permission in android manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. Add the dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  path_provider: any
  permission_handler: 4.4.0 //For asking permission to load the pdf
```

3. Then use the PDFView

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String urlPDFPath = "";
  bool exists = true;
  int _totalPages = 0;
  int _currentPage = 0;
  bool pdfReady = false;
  PDFViewController _pdfViewController;
  bool loaded = false;

  Future<File> getFileFromUrl(String url, {name}) async {
    var fileName = 'testonline';
    if (name != null) {
      fileName = name;
    }
    try {
      var data = await http.get(url);
      var bytes = data.bodyBytes;
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      File file = File("${dir.path}/" + fileName + ".pdf");
      print(dir.path);
      File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      return urlFile;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Error opening url file");
    }
  }

  void requestPersmission() async {
    await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    requestPersmission();
    getFileFromUrl("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf").then(
      (value) => {
        setState(() {
          if (value != null) {
            urlPDFPath = value.path;
            loaded = true;
            exists = true;
          } else {
            exists = false;
          }
        })
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(urlPDFPath);
    if (loaded) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: PDFView(
          filePath: urlPDFPath,
          autoSpacing: true,
          enableSwipe: true,
          pageSnap: true,
          swipeHorizontal: true,
          nightMode: false,
          onError: (e) {
            //Show some error message or UI
          },
          onRender: (_pages) {
            setState(() {
              _totalPages = _pages;
              pdfReady = true;
            });
          },
          onViewCreated: (PDFViewController vc) {
            setState(() {
              _pdfViewController = vc;
            });
          },
          onPageChanged: (int page, int total) {
            setState(() {
              _currentPage = page;
            });
          },
          onPageError: (page, e) {},
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
              iconSize: 50,
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (_currentPage > 0) {
                    _currentPage--;
                    _pdfViewController.setPage(_currentPage);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(
              "${_currentPage + 1}/$_totalPages",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
              iconSize: 50,
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (_currentPage < _totalPages - 1) {
                    _currentPage++;
                    _pdfViewController.setPage(_currentPage);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      if (exists) {
        //Replace with your loading UI
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Demo"),
          ),
          body: Text(
            "Loading..",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        //Replace Error UI
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Demo"),
          ),
          body: Text(
            "PDF Not Available",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your answer, but I get this error:
"The name 'File' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
'Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'File'."

Comment: You have to import some things before doing it, I updated my answer. For file you need to import 'dart:io'.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to run it, but unfortunately it doesn't work, and when I try to present the PDF file, I can these errors:
"[onError, {error: cannot create document: File not in PDF format or corrupted.}]"
"cannot create document: File not in PDF format or corrupted."
"Trying to embed a platform view but the PrerollContext does not support embedding"
"Trying to embed a platform view but the PaintContext does not support embedding"

Just note the URL PDF I am trying to present IS in PDF format (please see the link in the question above).
Thank you!!

Comment: I've solved your problem and updated the answer. The problem was that the pdfView was trying to load an empty String.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to load the file (for example, I can see the correct number of pages), but it just presents a blank file (white screen with the page arrows in the bottom)

Comment: Can you try other links for example this https://papers.xtremepape.rs/CAIE/IGCSE/Mathematics%20-%20Additional%20(0606)/0606_s11_qp_12.pdf

Comment: It seems to be working on Android but not on iOS. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: There is additional setup needed for Ios. Visit the plugin page https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

Comment: I've run the app on Android and it shows a blank page. Any idea why? (On iOS to works perfectly fine)

Comment: There maybe a problem in release mode if you use progaurd. Add this line if you are using progaurd `-keep class com.shockwave.**`

Comment: It's not working in debug mode, and I'm not using progaurd. Any other idea?

Comment: Not sure. Can you provide the error if you have any

Comment: I get this error message `error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:`

Comment: Does this happen to all links? And are you sure that you gave the app permission?

Comment: Yes, the app requests permission and when I approve it the blank page shows

Comment: I dont know then, probably something related to progaurd. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595321/

Comment: I don't use progaurd, and it's in debug mode not production

Comment: I've found the bug. The problem was that the fileName was written in non-English letters. Seems like the package reads English-only chars on Android. I've changed it to a static String and it seems to work fine

Answer (score 16):

u can use [flutter_cached_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview)

it is a Super of flutter_pdfview 
get with a lot of methods to help u to work faster with pdf

and this an example to view a pdf from URL and cache it

```
      PDF().cachedFromUrl('http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'),
```

and it has all features of flutter_pdfview

take a look https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview

Comment: This package is not null safety anymore hence don't think it's suitable to be used

Comment: @ZXERSTON
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview/versions/0.4.0-nullsafety

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for a way to solve this problem, I tried what was mentioned in the previous answers, and I did not get a good result, and after searching and trying several libraries, I found one that worked for me at first, I hope it helps you To you too
[syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: 'Syncfusion PDF Viewer Demo',
  home: HomePage(),
 ));
}

 /// Represents Homepage for Navigation
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
 }

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.bookmark,
          color: Colors.white,
          semanticLabel: 'Bookmark',
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          _pdfViewerKey.currentState?.openBookmarkView();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: SfPdfViewer.network(
    'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter- 
    succinctly.pdf',
    key: _pdfViewerKey,
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: This is a pay package

Comment: Sometimes things cost money for better results.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried using the [pdf_render](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_render) package, and it worked for me, this package can also load pdf documents directly from the url.

```
PdfViewer.openFutureFile(
      // Accepting function that returns Future<String> of PDF file path
      () async => (await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(
              'https://github.com/espresso3389/flutter_pdf_render/raw/master/example/assets/hello.pdf'))
          .path,
      viewerController: controller,
      onError: (err) => print(err),
      params: const PdfViewerParams(
        padding: 10,
        minScale: 1.0,
        // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      ),
    ))
```