# What is the best pdf viewer package for flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, pdf-generation, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have been trying pdf packages one by one. Most of them crushed and not working. One package is working which is `flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer` but it loads per page and feel slow. I am looking for the pdf viewer package which loads and scroll smoothly like adobe pdf reader (not good that much, but something like this).
Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Flutter app may be slow in debug mode. But when you test release it will work fine.

Comment: check out this one: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fullpdfview

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this community: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more - this question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: Don't quite understand why can't ask this kind of question. The purpose of this website is helping programmer to develop  application, right? Ask for recommendation of sdk is helpful anyway. I upvote for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flutter_pdfview (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview) is the fastest I have found so far. It's also relatively easy to use.

If you want to see how it is used, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62476333/9931959

Comment: For android Color OS this pdf view crash!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It might be a bug and may be fixed in the new update

Comment: I tried all df views in fluter but nothing works on Color OS

Comment: take a look https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview