# How to create a button that allows to view pdf in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want my users to view pdf only when they click on the button, so how can I do this in flutter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load and present a PDF file from the web in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476108/how-to-load-and-present-a-pdf-file-from-the-web-in-flutter)

Comment: your PDF saved locally or on the server?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package to view pdf if your PDF was saved on server.

example:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

  void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Network PDF Viewer"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              var url = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';
              launch(url, forceWebView: true);
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Open PDF',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```