# How to use Uri function properly in Flutter? Difference between Uri and Url

Tags: flutter, dart

I am confused with the URL and Uri in dart/flutter.

I created this function to be used in my PDF viewer.

```
static Future<File> loadNetwork(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final bytes = response.bodyBytes;

    return _storeFile(url, bytes);
  }
```

and I want to call this function to display the specific PDF after clicking a button.

```
  onTap: () async {
                            setState(() {
                            isLoading = true;
                               });
                            final url = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';
                            final file = await PDFApi.loadNetwork(url);
                            openPDF(context, file);
                            setState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                               });
                          },
```

But, still, how do I properly use the Uri and fetch the pdf link. There is an error and I suspect I am using the function wrongly.

It says invalid internet address.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but shouldn't this line have braces? `final Uri.http'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';`

Like this: `final Uri.http('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');`

Comment: Also there should be two arguments to it: more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html

Comment: @obywan I have edited the question, no error in code but when i press the button, it throws "invalid internet address", although address is correct

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your usage of `Uri`.  Your issue likely is https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83792 and should go away with a newer version of the Flutter SDK.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a url to Uri use `Uri.parse("url here")`

Comment: It says invalid intenet address

Comment: have you included http package https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: Yes I have included in my pubspec and imported it on top.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview
try this package

Comment: I am already using this package to display my pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476108/how-to-load-and-present-a-pdf-file-from-the-web-in-flutter
check this please